# write all file types to a file - ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I want to write the file type of all files in a folder to a file.

So this is what i did

```
for xfile in *.*
do
file "x$file"  > values     
done
```

But for my bad luck it didnt run. and the error message was

```
: command not found 
'/check.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'/check.sh: line 3: `do
```

Could someone please help me get over this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, your *variable* is `xfile` but you attempt to use the variable `file` preceded by the literal `x`. I think that `x$file` should be `$xfile`.

Secondly, you're executing the `file` command for each file and overwriting the `values` file each time, meaning only the last one will appear. You can fix this by deleting the file up front and using `>>` (append) instead of `>` (overwrite).

Thirdly, the `file` command is perfectly capable of handling multiple arguments so you really only need:

```
file * >values
```

That also uses `*` because `*.*` is a Windows/DOS thingie - if you want all files under UNIX-like operating systems, `*` is the correct form (or `.*` as well if you want hidden files).

---

And finally, none of those suggestions above will fix your *actual* problem, which is almost certainly the presence of DOS-style line-endings in your file. That error message is a near *perfect* match to what you would see in that case.

On my system, when I input your script with DOS line endings, I get the same error message (mostly).

If you do an `od -xcb check.sh`, you will most likely see something like:

```
0000020    0a0d    6f64    0a0d    6966    656c    2220    7824    6966
         \r  \n   d   o  \r  \n   f   i   l   e       "   $   x   f   i
        015 012 144 157 015 012 146 151 154 145 040 042 044 170 146 151
```

with the `\r` characters indicating the incorrect line endings.

You can use your favorite (decent) editor to view and remove these or simply install `dos2unix` with `apt-get` (though you may already have this) and do:

```
# sudo apt-get install dos2unix  ## only if you don't have it already.
dos2unix check.sh >check2.sh
```

and then use `check2.sh`.

Although, keep in mind, the single-line:

```
file * >values
```

is still a better option than the `for` loop (but you'll still want to ensure you're using UNIX line endings).